# Existence of a matrix norm where $\|AB\| = \|A\|\|B\|$ for all $A,B\in M_n$

Tags: matrices, proof-verification, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

> Is it possible to have a matrix norm on $M_n$ where $n>1$ such that $\|AB\| = \|A\|\|B\|$ for all $A,B\in M_n$?

I am very inclined to say *no*, there does not exist a matrix norm where equality is always possible. We know that by definition of a matrix norm, $\|X\| = 0 \iff X = O$. Consider some matrices $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots &0\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots\\0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots &0\end{bmatrix},\;\;\; B = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots &0\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots\\0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots &1\end{bmatrix} \in M_n.$$

Obviously, $A\ne O$ and $B\ne O$, but $AB = O$. Hence $\|AB\| = \|O\| = 0$, but since $A,B \ne O$, then $\|A\|,\|B\| >0$ which implies $\|A\|\|B\| > 0$ which is not zero.

Is this valid reasoning to believe no such norm exists over $M_n$?

My professor was somewhat vague saying that "*usually* submultiplicativity equality doesn't happen." Why *usually*? I unfortunately did not get a very satisfactory answer when I asked about the "usually" part. That might imply there does exist, but logically one doesn't seem to exist. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Your argument is fine. If the norm is multiplicative, nonzero elements are closed under multiplication, and this is not the case for matrices of size $\geqslant 2$.

Comment: When an instructor says "usually," I interpret him as meaning, "usually, when working."  So, in other words, he means "usually when I am working with matrices, equality doesn't hold."  There is no logical reason for this.  It is just an incidental fact about his experience working with matrices.